# Add content to an existing .zip file

Tags: export

I have been looking over the .zip documentation from Mathematica (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/ZIP.html). It seems pretty straighforward  to export and import from/to a .zip file, but how can i add content to an existing .zip file?

Comment: you need to import the whole thing, add your content and re-export.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the structure of zip files in a way that is not specific to _Mathematica_.

Comment: @m_goldberg while it may not work out of the box the question is still valid and perhaps someone will come up with a clever solution.

Comment: the zip format is open. You'll need to read and reconstruct the central directory to include reference to your new file.  Seems *do-able*, on the other hand there are plenty of simple command line utilies that already do this so why reinvent the wheel?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802097/how-does-one-find-the-start-of-the-central-directory-in-zip-files

Comment: Since there are utility apps available that *can* add a file or files to an existing `.zip`, and at least "out of the box" *Mathematica* cannot do such, it doesn't seem off-topic to have the question here.